# Translate Chinese `收腹` (an abdomen exercise) to proper words

Tags: verbs, translation

I tried to translate `收腹` from Chinese to English.

`收腹` is something like: use you power/muscles of abdomen to force abdomen **shrink/swallow**(In fact, I also don't know if I use the correct verb here..).
`收` is a verb which has many means in English, at here, I think it is `shrink`. `腹` is abdomen.

I searched for the translations on some translation sites, got `abdomen in`, `abdomen flat`, `stomach in`, `pull your stomachs` and `keep your stomach muscles in`. Only the last one seems correct(my feeling). And google translation even give me only `Abdomen` ...

I also search `收起腹部`(same meaning of `收腹`), some site give me `belly up` ...

What is the correct translation ? If `abdomen in` or `abdomen flat` is correct, could you explain what is the composition of them?

Comment: We could say "To get a *flat* stomach, you can do {this exercise}."  For example, a "stomach crunch".

Comment: Possibly *tuck in your tummy*. Probably not *belly up* - that's a reference to [the posture of fish when they are ill or dead](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2015/03/fish-float-upside-die/), and used as a figure of speech in other contexts.

Comment: Is this the name of the exercise itself (sit-up, lunge, bench press), or a literal instruction to perform as part of a larger exercise (straighten your arm, etc)? Is this related to any particular sport or regimen (weight lifting, wushu, tai-qi)? Can you provide pictures?

Comment: What is your sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, you can say **tighten your abdominal muscles**. Here is an example:

> **Tighten your abdominal muscles** and your buttock muscles together to tilt your pelvis back- wards and flatten your lower spine. - [The complete guide to abdominal training](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=iSxLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA87&dq=%22tighten%20your%20abdominal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNgYyu3rPOAhVE7xQKHVUrBEAQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22tighten%20your%20abdominal%22&f=false)

Informally, you can say **tighten your tummy muscles**. Here is an example:

> ... feel the air going out of your body. Once it stops going out of your body, **tighten your tummy muscles** very gently - [Stretching and pregnancy](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=0rZTyF4LX2EC&q=%22tighten%20your%20tummy%22&dq=%22tighten%20your%20tummy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj9PTk3bPOAhXJRhQKHYDCC_8Q6AEIOTAF)

Comment: Another common informal word for the abdominal muscles is simply the "abs", as in "tighten your abs".